# Concat a video and an audio using ffmpeg, freezing the last video frame, without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat a video (mp4) and an audio (mp4 or aac) - both cut out using `-ss` and `-t` from the same mp4 file. I'd like to basically freeze the last frame from the video and then append the audio.

I've tried using the concat demuxer `-f conat` and `-c copy`, but it produces a video of wrong duration (much longer than it should be, so I'm thinking some PTS are wrong in the audio, how can I reset them?). Also, bad output using `-i concat:video_cut.mp4|audio_cut.mp4`

I also wonder if it's possible to do whole treat in one call of ffmpeg making use of `filter_complex`: apply certain filters to one part of video (`drawbox`, `drawtext`), then freeze a frame and continue audio as is.

Thank you!

Comment: try freezeframes: `ffmpeg -to 5 -i input.mp4 -ss 3 -to 4 -i input.mp4 -lavfi "drawtext=text='test',drawbox,freezeframes=first=50:last=125" -c:a copy out.mp4`